# Where this 'i' came from?

Tags: reactjs

In React tutorial, they build a tic-tac-toe game. It was easy to understand until i got this code:

```
handleClick(i) {
        const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
        squares[i] = 'X';
        this.setState({squares : squares});
}
```

This code is a handler for a click event. But I didn't get where this 'i' variable in the code came from. how do React knows the exact button I'm clicking? Can anyone who read the tutorial explain it for me, please?

Here goes the full code (I changed the `onClick` prop to `onActivation` for personal purposes):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';


class Square extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <button
                className="square"
                onClick={() => this.props.onActivation()}>
                {this.props.value}
            </button>
        );
    }
}
class Board extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(9).fill(null),
        }
    }
    handleClick(i) {
        const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
        squares[i] = 'X';
        this.setState({squares : squares});
    }
    renderSquare(i) {
        return (
            <Square
            value={this.state.squares[i]}
            onActivation={()=>this.handleClick(i)}
            />
        );
    }
    render(){
        const status = "Next Player: X";
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="status">{status}</div>
            <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(0)}
            {this.renderSquare(1)}
            {this.renderSquare(2)}
            </div>
            <div>
            {this.renderSquare(3)}
            {this.renderSquare(4)}
            {this.renderSquare(5)}
            </div>
            <div>
            {this.renderSquare(6)}
            {this.renderSquare(7)}
            {this.renderSquare(8)}
            </div>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

class Game extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="game">
            <div className="game-board">
            <Board/>
            </div>
            <div className="game-info">
        <div>{/* status */}</div>
    <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
    </div>
    </div>
    )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Game/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: The `i` is an argument to the method...

Comment: I know, but where the value came from in handleClick(i)? It's executed only when I click, right?

Comment: What do you mean? The value is passed to the method

Comment: I click the button, it calls onActivation(), which in turn calls handleClick(i), but I can't see where this i is coming from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the variables and functions until you find the source.

Starting with `squares[i] = 'X';`, that line is inside a function `handleClick()` which has `i` as it's parameter. `handleClick()` is called called within `onActivation={()=>this.handleClick(i)}`, which is in the `renderSquare()` function, which again has `i` as a parameter. `renderSquare()` is used within the component's `render()` method, where each use of `renderSquare()` is passed a numerical argument.

For example, `this.renderSquare(7)`. In this case, the number `7` is passed through `renderSquare` to `handleClick` to `squares[i]`.

If you're the visual type
[image]

Comment: Ok, I got it, but  `handleClick(i)` is only called when I click the button, right? So, that `i` value is saved somewhere? I just can't see where the value is storaged.

Comment: Yes. `this.handleClick()` is called called `onClick` of each `Square` component. Each `Square` component is created by calling the `renderSquare()` function, which has a value (`i`) passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the 'i' is hoisted in the scope of `renderSquare()`, that's why it can be used by `handleCLick()`